# unable to lazy load UIImageview of different frame size in UIScrollView.

Tags: ios, ios4

I am adding imageview gallery in scroll view. Images are coming from server & they dont have specific size so i have to display each image with specified frame from server image. but problem comes when image size becomes more apllication crashes. I tried to implement lazy loading but not able to do it successfully

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` to display your images. Since simultaneous downloads can cause a problem. Try this [open source project](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code and it is working fine for me http://www.mindyourcode.com/ios/lazy-loading-image-download/
But you may clear your cache when you think you have enough load. In this tutorial they are using table view with default behaviour but you can change direction of your tableView like this

```
CGRect frame = tblView.frame;
tblView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(stressTblView.transform, M_PI / 2);
tblView.frame = frame;
```

then show images in the cells of your UITableView and It doesn't matter what is the hieght and width of your image, in this case. 
Well again I am not sure if this is your solution.